# When the number of parameters is different, can it not work normally?

Tags: python

```
    def cala(dec1, bet, cashz):
        global playercash1_1
        global batcash1_1   
        global playercash1_2
        global batcash1_2
        if bet == 1:
            playercash1_1 -= cashz/2
            batcash1_1 += cashz/2                
            playercash11.configure(text = playercash1_1)
            battingcash1_1.configure(text = batcash1_1)
            switch(dec1, bet)
        elif bet == 2: 
            playercash1_1 -= cashz/2
            batcash1_1 += cashz/2  
            playercash11.configure(text = playercash1_1)
            battingcash1_1.configure(text = batcash1_1 )
            switch(dec1, bet)
        elif bet == 4:   
            playercash1_2 -= cashz/2
            batcash1_2 += cashz/2  
            playercash22.configure(text = playercash1_2)
            battingcash1_2.configure(text = batcash1_2)
            switch(dec1, bet)
        elif bet == 5:  
            playercash1_2 -= cashz/2 
            batcash1_2 += cashz/2
            playercash22.configure(text = playercash1_2)
            battingcash1_2.configure(text = batcash1_2)
            switch(dec1, bet)
        else:
            switch(dec1, bet)                


            
    def switch(dec1, bet):
        if raisebutton1["state"] == "normal":
            raisebutton1["state"] = "disabled"
            checkbutton1["state"] = "disabled"
            foldbutton1["state"] = "disabled"
            raisebutton2["state"] = "normal"
            checkbutton2 ["state"] = "normal"
            foldbutton2 ["state"] = "normal"
            button_pressed(dec1, bet)
            
        elif raisebutton2["state"] == "normal":
            raisebutton1 ["state"] = "normal"
            checkbutton1 ["state"] = "normal"
            foldbutton1 ["state"] = "normal"
            raisebutton2["state"] = "disabled"
            checkbutton2 ["state"] = "disabled"
            foldbutton2 ["state"] = "disabled"
            button_pressed(dec1, bet)
```

After executing cala(dec1, bet, cashz) and calculating when the number put into bet is 1, I try to execute switch(dec1, bet), but it is not executed.

```
            playercash1_1 -= cashz/2
            batcash1_1 += cashz/2                
            playercash11.configure(text = playercash1_1)
            battingcash1_1.configure(text = batcash1_1)
```

This code executes correctly, but the def switch is the code that changes the state, so I don't understand logically why this doesn't work rather than calculating.